Google Lighthouse flags issues that would be penalised for SEO. Can these be false positives?
Summary
I have a site that is created using the Elementor Page Builder in Wordpress. 
Elementor allows for us to use certain widgets such as:

Button Widgets (used for several button links)
Toggle Widgets (used for our FAQ section)

Based on how the widgets have been designed, Google Lighthouse has flagged out several issues that would be penalised for SEO -- these are false positives. But we wanted to check with the community whether Google Search Engine would penalise these implementation?
Please find the PageSpeed Insights Report here!
Button Widgets
These button widgets have the html elements generated such that the href link does not have a descriptive text (from Google Lighthouse perspective). The descriptive text is in a child element of the button link, hence the button would still be meaningful for the users. Please see the screenshot below for reference:

Google Lighthouse Findings
Google Lighthouse infers that there is no descriptive text for the button. We are note sure whether Google Search SEO ranking algorithm would infer the same (wanted some inputs from the community based on their experience here):

Toggle Widgets
The toggle widgets are used for our FAQ section. These are not intended to be links but the widget by default has an a anchor tag. Since it has an a anchor tag, Google Lighthouse infers these to be links.
Since these are not links, they are not crawl able (they do not lead anywhere). Google lighthouse flags this as an issue that will be penalised (since there are non-crawl able links).
See screenshot below for reference:

Google Lighthouse Findings
Google lighthouse advised that non-crawl able links would be penalised:

Clarification

For the button link that has "no text description". Would this be penalised by Google Search Engine SEO?
For the "non-crawl able" links in the FAQ section. Would this be penalised by Google Search Engine SEO?

Thank You
Thanks in advance, please let me know if there are further details that I can give to assist with the above clarifications.

The lack of description actually refers to the link on the mobile view.  For some reason, the mobile version shows a different link.  The text on the mobile button is just "Learn more".
Whilst hidden with CSS for desktop, the code is still there, so PageSpeed insights will also flag it as a desktop issue.
It's not a major issue, but descriptive links give a signal to Google what a page is about. You won't get penalised for it, but you won't be rewarded for it, either.
The Toggle Widgets issue is just about writing semantic HTML. Again, it's not going to get you a penalty but it's always a good habit to use the correct tags, for accessibility as well as SEO.  The clearer your code is, the less likely it is to be misunderstood.

Hi there,
Wanted to close the loop, thanks for the response.
Had fixed  the mobile button link description, and the issue disappeared.
We can checkout the revised report here:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-petcoach-sg/12km58s6hr?form_factor=mobile
